# Is it possible to run nodejs server and react server on single port?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to run both react and node on single server because i don't want to start it together.
like when i run npm start both will be run because i want to run project using electronjs.

I tried to run command `npm start client.js server.js` but it didn't work

Comment: You cannot run two things on the same port <fullstop>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't run 2 servers in the same port and the same IP you should run each one on a different port, react has a default port(3000) to run on you should set your nodejs server to another one like 8000.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that you'll need two different port numbers `3000` for server `3001` client...
otherwise, you can use **Docker** to run on the same port and map to your host on different ports with docker commands:

`docker run CLIENT_IMAGE -p 3000:3000`
`docker run SERVER_IMAGE -p 3001:3000`

Comment: This question is about node, not docker